# In Kürze wird sich der Sie behandelnde Arzt um Sie kümmern

Tags: grammatical-case, grammaticality, participle

I had a visit to the doctor in Germany, and in the reception this sign greeted me:

> Herlich Willkommen!
>
> Bitte nehmen Sie platz. Halten Sie ggf. Ihre Versicherungskarte und den Überweisungsschein bereit. **In Kürze wird sich der Sie behandelnde Arzt um Sie kümmern**

That last sentence got me confused. Specially with the "der Sie".

I have an idea of what it is trying to say, but I do not understand the way that sentence it was built. What is that??

**PS:** I am healthy, thanks if you are curios ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an example of a sentence containing a **„[Partizipgruppe](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Partizip.html?MenuId=Sentence35)“**: „der Sie behandelnde Arzt“ is the *Partizipgruppe*.

You can transform the sentence, resolving the Partizipgruppe into a subordinate clause:

> "der Arzt, der Sie behandelt".

Regarding the structure of the sentence: In a *Partizipgruppe*, the extending element (here: the simple pronoun „Sie“) is placed in front of the participle („behandelnde Arzt”), but after the article. Thus, using a Partizipgruppe in this case results in the unfamiliar structure

> article („der“) - personal pronoun as object („Sie“) - participle clause („behandelnde Arzt“).

Answer (score 7):

Literal:

> Soon the you-treating Doctor will will take care of you.

Same meaning, but other construction:

> In Kürze wird sich der Arzt, der Sie behandelt, um Sie kümmern.
>   Soon the doctor, who is treating you, will take care of you.

You also can turn sentences like this

> Der Mann, der das Pferd zähmt, raucht.
>   The man who tames the horse smokes.

into this:

> Der das Pferd zähmende Mann raucht.
>   *The horse-taming man smokes.*

Comment: The better translation instead of "will care about you" would be "will take care of you". "to care about someone" steht dafür, dass die Person jemandem etwas bedeutet oder jemandem wichtig ist.

Comment: @Javatasse: Danke, ich habe es korrigiert.